# Stop Azure DevOps pipelines from automatically creating Environments when the Environment does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I recently ran a multistage pipeline where it points to an environment for deployment. I created the environment beforehand and applied approvals since it’s Production and also to be Sox compliant. However, what happened was that there was a typo in the environment and the pipeline went ahead and created a new environment with the typo name, even scarier was that the deployment went to production. How can I stop the pipeline from auto-creating environments? This appears to be a big loophole and I guess there should be some setting that I can turn off.

I referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/pipelines/sprint-188-update. This still does not address my issue. Is there any way to disconnect user contexts from the pipeline so that the auto-creation of environments does not happen?

Comment: What we've done in the past is have a stage or a single task that does some pre-checks by calling the Azure API. For example you can get a list of Environment names to check they exist and ending the process if it does not exist. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Thanks, Mike, appreciate your input. But again, the developers develop the pipelines and the higher-up management manages the environment and controls the release to the production. If the developer forgets to add this task, the situation will still remain the same. I understand that your idea will solve this problem to some extent. For some reason, I think Microsoft has not addressed this loophole satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Changes in the automatic creation of environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/pipelines/sprint-188-update)

> we handled this case by adding all the project contributors to the administrator role of the environment. Any member of the project could then change these permissions and prevent others from accessing the environment.

By default, if the user is a member of the Contributor Group or Project Administrator Group in project, the user will have access to create the Environment when running YAML Pipeline.

You can navigate to **Pipelines -> Environments -> Security** and check the permission.

[image]

> Is there any way to disconnect user contexts from the pipeline so that the auto-creation of environments does not happen?

When you run the YAML Pipeline, it will create the related environment via the user account who run the pipeline.

To meet the requirement, you can remove the Creator role of Contributor Group/Project Administrator Group.

For example:

[image]

Then only the users in the Project Collection Administrator Group will have access to auto create the environment.

Other users will see the following error when running the YAML pipeline.

[image]